# Blocking a specific external IP:Port connection in RedHat?

Tags: rhel, iptables, socket

I know that in RedHat, in the IP tables I can block incoming connections to a local port. I can also block connections from a specific IP.

But is it possible to block a connection from a specific IP address and the connection attempt is made from a service running at a specific port on the external IP?

So if I had something like,

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 202.54.20.22 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 202.54.20.22 -j DROP
```

Can I specify more specificity for that particular IP address and select a specific port to block? Let's say the service is running on port 5000 at 202.54.20.22, can I be that specific? Note that this service may not attempt to connect to port 5000 on the server, so just blocking that port on the server isn't what I am after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the rules you're looking for:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 202.54.20.22 --sport 5000 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 202.54.20.22 --dport 5000 -j DROP
```

If the service sends UDP packets, you have to change `-p tcp` with `-p udp`.

Comment: Shouldn't the first rule use -s instead of -d since it's an incoming rule and 202.54.20.22 would be the source of the incoming traffic?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I edited my answer.